# git cherry picking to a different base directory

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

I have certain commits in a branch, 10.57, which I want to merge to another branch 10.58.

I would normally cherry-pick those commits from 10.57 to 10.58.

There is however a glitch. Certain files have changed their directory structure in 10.58.

**Example**: The source dir `MAAS/ios-web-services` in 10.57 has moved to `MAAS/apple/ios-web-services` in 10.58.

If I cherry pick as before my changes would created afresh as new files/directories in `MAAS/ios-web-services` instead of getting merged to files in `MAAS/apple/ios-web-services`.

Is there a way I can ask git to factor in this change in directory structure?

[Git cherry pick files, from Directory A to Directory B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544801/git-cherry-pick-files-from-directory-a-to-directory-b) seems to suggest editing patches and applying them manually. Is there no other easier way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two branches with different directory hierarchies in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722423/how-to-merge-two-branches-with-different-directory-hierarchies-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

If the files only have minor changes you can try using `merge.renameLimit` as described for merging branches here: [How to merge two branches with different directory hierarchies in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13118734/1279521)

Answer (score 0):

1. On 10.58, create a directory structure same as 10.57
   mkdir -p MAAS/ios-web-services
2. Move the files from old location to newly created location
   mv MAAS/apple/ios-web-services/* MAAS/ios-web-services/
3. Commit these changes
   git add MAAS/ios-web-services
   git commit -a
4. Now cherry pick the change from 10.57 to 10.58
5. Reverse step 2 i.e move the files from new location to old location
6. Reverse step1 i.e delete the directory structure
7. Commit these changes.
8. Now you have 3 commits, first at step 3, second at step 4, third at step 7. Merge all 3 commits with git rebase -i HEAD~3